# Kafka subscriber getting only alternate messages

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have a topic cars, with only 1 partition and 1 replication factor as shown below:

`Topic:cars PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: cars Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0`

I have two brokers running, one on 9092 and other on 9093 on my localhost.

My java application sends messages to the topic cars. I am seeing a very odd behavior.

1. My java application is only receiving alternate messages such as message #1, message #3.. and so on

In order to debug this issue, i started a console consumer. Now i could see ONLY those messages that my java application was not getting. For example, message #2, message #4 .. and so on

Its clear that my messages are correctly being post to the topic, so, what is causing my java application to receive only alternate messages?

And lastly, why consumer console is only demonstrating the above behavior?

Comment: That seems odd. Would you mind sharing your application code ?

Comment: I am facing same issue using Pentaho ETL tool